# javascript google maps api remove markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have functions that when a li element is clicked markers are added to the map. If another li is clicked then the original markers are removed and the new one appearr.

The issue I am having is that the markers are placed on the map when a li is clicked for the first time. When a second li is clicked the markers are removed but the new ones are not added. I get no error in firebug. I cant see what I am missing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".markerSelection").click(function() {
      var selectionId = $(this).attr("id");
      drop(selectionId);
    }); 
});



var markers = {
    shopping : [
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26183, -7.11339),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26134, -7.11226),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26067, -7.11181),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26003, -7.11033)],
    cars : [
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26183, -7.11339),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26134, -7.11226),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26067, -7.11181),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.26003, -7.11033)] 
};

var iterator = 0; 

function drop(selectionId) {
    clearOverlays();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers[selectionId].length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    addMarker(selectionId);
    }, i * 200);
    }
}

function addMarker(selectionId) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markers[selectionId][iterator],
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    iterator++;
    markersArray.push(marker);
}

// Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
function clearOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you post a live example that exhibits the problem, maybe a fiddle.  How is this post different from [your other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486011/javascript-google-map-api-remove-markets-and-show-new)?  I would have thought you could have updated that one.

Comment: In my previous question I was asking what is the best way to pass a string and get a variable based on that. One answer was to use an object which as you can see I have implemented. The above code does work to a certain degree, i though there might be something very obvious that I have missed. I will have a look at making a jsfiddle version, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code one more time, and I think the problem is with `iterator`, which is initialized to 0 in global scope. That is why the first time it works okay, but after that, indices exceed. It seems you should set it to zero at the beginning of the `drop()` function. 
However it makes more sense if you pass index as a second parameter of `addMarker()` instead of an outer variable which is handled in `drop()` and complicate you code.

Comment: Thank you very much Alireza for your help. Well spotted

Answer (score 0):

You have defined *`markers`* as a Json variable, but I don't know what you mean by `markers[selectionId]`! Markers is not defined as an array and it seems it's not correct to refer to it by index!

Comment: markers is an object, I pass into it shopping or cars through selectionId

Comment: Yes you are right ;) I don't know why I assumed selectionId is a number!